# Import and display a jpeg from a SQL Server database using r

Tags: sql, r, image, jpeg

Work has asked us to import a series of jpeg files from a SQL Server database for display on a dashboard product we have. We are using R to query our db and build our dashboards so we need to be able to import the images from SQL Server and display them (or at least export to a local system folder).

We can pull down and display standard table information like File Name, File Size, File Type, and File Data `<raw>`, but we are having a hard time understanding how to extract and display the jpeg files.

[image: table of image details]

I know they are stored in the database in a `varbinary` column types, but the standard read/writeJPEG() doesn't seem to like anything without a file path, for example pulling the data directly from the SQL Server database into r.

Tried pulling a single file for export to local folder, but same problem with loading the image.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `jpeg::readJPEG` function says it can read from raw vectors and you seem to have raw vectors in your data.frame. So try something like

```
jpeg::readJPEG(dd$FileData[[1]])
```

For something reproducible, here's an example that reads a sample image from the `jpeg` package in as a raw vector and then turns that into an image object

```
#sample data
fname <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg")
filedataraw <- readBin(fname, "raw", file.info(fname)$size)
```

Now that we've created a sample raw vector (like the one that's presumably stored in your dataframe), we can parse the image data with the `jpeg` library

```
img <- jpeg::readJPEG(filedataraw)
plot(1:2, type='n')
rasterImage(img, 1.2, 1.27, 1.8, 1.73)
```

If the goal is just to write to a file, you don't need to parse the file as a JPEG at all. You can just write the bytes to disk.

```
writeBin(filedataraw, "sample.jpeg")
```

Comment: Thank you for the direction. So I tried the readJPEG() and received output that appears to be vector values rather than an actual image. Do you think the raw data may need to be processed in a different way?

Comment: Well readJPEG just decides the image data. What do you want to do with that data? Did you try plotting the data as I did above?

Comment: I did, unfortunately no success. The fname <- system.file function looks like it's trying to call from a local directory, but since the image file is stored on a sql db I can't figure out how to correctly point it to the right location.

Comment: @CL3ad What exactly does "no success" mean? What's going wrong? What is the end goal?

Comment: I am trying to pull the image files from a sql db and save them to a local directory. A single image would be a great start, but the end goal is to pull numerous images in bulk for a given event.

Comment: @CL3ad I added some code to write the raw data to disk. Without a reproducible example, I can't test it in your data, but you don't need to bother with `readJPEG` at all in that case.

Comment: I will give it a go.

Comment: ...Worked immediately! Thank you! Any tips on how to export in bulk?

Comment: Loop over the list of FileData values (vectors). I can't really tell much about how your data is stored from that picture so it's difficult to be any more specific.